# Modified Bessel Function Identity (change of variable integrating on the sphere)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions, spheres, stiefel-manifolds

Can someone explain why the following identity regarding the modified Bessel function of the first kind holds?

$$\int_{\mathbb{S}^{p-1}} e^{\kappa \mu^T\mathbf{x}}d\mathbf{x} = B\left(\frac{p-1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)^{-1} \int_{-1}^{1} e^{\kappa t} (1 - t^2)^{(p-3)/2}dt = \Gamma\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\kappa}{2}\right)^{1-p/2} I_{p/2-1}(\kappa)$$

where $\kappa > 0$, $\mathbb{S}^{p-1} = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^p: \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x} = 1\}$ is the unit sphere,  $\mu$ is a unit vector such that $\mu^T\mu = 1$ (i.e. $\mu \in \mathbb{S}^{p-1}$), $B(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the beta function and $I_{\nu}(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

While the second equality is simple to derive from the definition of $I_{\nu}(x)$ (see for example https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32), I do not understand how to perform the change of variable in the first equality.

For reference, the above chain of equalities is reported in equation (9.3.6) in Mardia and Jupp (2000), *Directional Statistics*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotate the sphere or choose coordinate axes so that $\boldsymbol\mu$ becomes the direction of a coordinate axis (say $t$) and now you have the orthogonal $(p-2)$-sphere of radius $\sqrt{1-t^2}$ where the integrand takes the same value $e^{\kappa t}$:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{S}^{p-1}}e^{\kappa {\boldsymbol \mu}^T\mathbf{x}}\,\mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}^{p-1}(\mathbf{x}) = \int_{-1}^1 e^{\kappa t}\left(\int_{\mathbb{S}^{p-2}(\sqrt{1-t^2}) }\,\mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}^{p-2}\right)\,\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
$$
and we know $\mathcal{H}^{p-2}(\mathbb{S}^{p-2})=\frac{2\pi^{(p-1)/2}}{\Gamma(\frac12(p-1))}$.

---

**Edit**: The difference between the factor $\mathcal{H}^{p-2}(\mathbb{S}^{p-2})$ and your $\mathrm{B}(\frac{p-1}{2},\frac12)^{-1}$ appears to come from whether you normalise the measure on $\mathbb{S}^{p-1}$ to $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I start to see why. How is this related to the tangent-normal decomposition then? We know that every unit vector can be decomposed as 
$$\mathbf{x} = t \mu + \sqrt{1-t^2} \xi,$$ where $\mu \in \mathbb{S}^{p-1}$, $\xi \in \mathbb{S}^{p-2}$ and $\mu^T \xi = 0$ (?). However, I cannot just replace this formula inside the first integral. Many thanks